# TeXstudio problem compiling

Tags: texstudio, input, include, chapterbib

I am writing a long document (thesis). I have a `main.tex` file, and several individual files, for each thesis' chapter. These files are included in the main file using the `\include` command.
I had trouble generating the bibliography for each section (chapterbib), finally I discovered that for some unknown reason the TeXstudio was not generating the .bbl files properly. In order to compile I had to generate the .bbl files and then manually change the extension from .bbl to .tex.bbl and then recompile.

It worked properly in my laptop at home, but now I am trying to recompile the file at work but when I do it in TeXstudio it generates a blank file, I've realized that this happens when I use the `\include` command instead of `\input`, the problem with `\input` is that it does not generate the bibliographies properly. What can be preventing the TeXstudio to compile my thesis properly at work while it works normally at home. I have checked all the usual stuff, same version, same folder's structure, same parameters, same .tex files. Is there any known issue with the `\include` command?

Comment: `chapterbib` needs to use `\include`. So there isn't an issue using `\include`, but there may be an issue using `\input`. In such a case, you would need to use `cbunit` or `\cbinput`. Note: `chapterbib` needs BibTeX runs for each `aux`-file of the included files. AFAIK TeXstudio can handle only one BibTeX run per document itself. So maybe you either have to do the BibTeX runs for the other `aux`-files from the terminal window or configure TeXstudio to use `latexmk` or use [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with [`biber`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) instead of `chapterbib`.

Comment: Can you include a example file in your question so that others can replicate what you obtain? Write a main.tex and show how you include the bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution which is not totally practical, but it does the job for me, I am just learning LaTeX. For some unknown reason, the problem whit the \input \include commands were solved by re-installing TeXstudio, however as it was mentioned, the bibliography for each individual section needs to be generated using bibtex in the terminal, then the extension of the .bbl files needs to be changed (manually) to .tex.bbl and finally the file generated either from TeXstudio or from terminal using pdflatex.